# check if new DateTime is today or future in php

Tags: php

I need to check if date1 is today or future date and if so its ok
if not (is in the past) its not ok. i see a lot of examples but none of theme is check if date1 is equal today.
my code is:

```
$today = new DateTime(); // Today
$today->format('Y-m-d'); //2016-10-27
$contractDateBegin = new DateTime($date1); //2016-10-27

if($today->getTimestamp() <= $contractDateBegin->getTimestamp()){
   echo 'OK';
}
else{
   echo "NOT OK";
}
```

its work fine if date1 is a future date but if its the same date its echo "NOT OK"

any help?

Comment: i think a simple greater than sign should cut it. if($today->getTimestamp() > $contractDateBegin->getTimestamp()){
   echo 'OK';
} else  { do stuff}

Comment: Your `$today` is also taking into account the time. Using `$today = new DateTime('today midnight')` resolves this by forcing the time part to 0 (at which point you can just do `$today <= $contractDateBegin`). Not sure if there's a better option.

Comment: Thank you  Jon Stirling its working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`$today` can be defined as just `new DateTime("today")`, which means today at midnight -- the time part will be automatically zeroed out

```
$today = new DateTime("today"); 
$date1 = '2016-10-27';
$contractDateBegin = new DateTime($date1); //2016-10-27
if($today <= $contractDateBegin){
    echo 'OK';
}
else{
    echo "NOT OK";
}
```

**[DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/2ta)**

Answer (score 0):

The "Y-m-d format" is perfect also for direct lexicographical comparison of strings and there is no need to convert it to a DateTime object. With PHP7 you could use the famous [speceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) ;)

```
php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $today = '2016-10-27';
php > $tomorrow = '2016-10-28';
php > $today2 = '2016-10-27';

php > echo $today <=> $tomorrow;
-1
php > echo $today <=> $today2;
0
php > echo $tomorrow <=> $today2;
1
```

Answer (score 0):

`getTimestamp()` included "H:i:s". So it'll fail when compare the seconds.
In your case, do you want to compare just date('Y-m-d')?
If you just want to use DateTime and compare Timestamp. Please try

```
$today = new DateTime(); // Today
$contractDateBegin = new DateTime($date1); //2016-10-27

// Set time to 0
$today->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$contractDateBegin->setTime(0, 0, 0);

if($today->getTimestamp() <= $contractDateBegin->getTimestamp()){
   echo 'OK';
}
else{
   echo "NOT OK";
}
```

Comment: Hello Tam Nguyen your solution is working to... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only want to compare the dates (ignoring the time). This should work:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$today = $today->format('Y-m-d');
$contractDateBegin = new DateTime($date1);
$contractDateBegin = $contractDateBegin->format('Y-m-d');

if ($today <= $contractDateBegin){
    echo 'OK';
} else {
   echo "NOT OK";
}
```

Comment: Did you test the code you tell OP "should work"? Calling `format` doesn't change the object.

Comment: @JonStirling my fault. What I actually wanted was to reassign the variables.

Comment: While that update _might_ work (I have a feeling there could be edge cases) it just isn't a nice way of doing it. But I can't actually say it doesn't work, so will drop the downvote.

Comment: @JonStirling give me an example when this doesn't work?

Comment: Updated comment. I failed to find one. :P

Comment: It makes a simple string comparison which should work when both dates are Y-m-d. But yes, there are probably better ways.